# Probability, independent variables

Tags: probability-theory, independence

I was wondering how i would go about answering this following question:

Suppose that $X$ and $Y$ are independent random variables and $g$ is a real-valued function on $\Bbb{R}$. Show that $g(X)$ and $Y$ are independent.

Comment: If this is not a PSQ, I do not know what is. By a deliberate, repeating, offender...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $(\Omega, \Sigma, \textrm P)$ be a probability space. Two subsets $\Sigma_1, \Sigma_2 \subseteq \Sigma$ are called *independent* if $\forall A \in \Sigma_1, B \in \Sigma_2$
$$ \textrm{P}(A \cap B) = \textrm{P}(A) \cap \textrm{P}(B)$$
A function $f : \Omega \longrightarrow \mathbb R$ is called *borel measurable* if for $\mathcal B$ = σ-algebra of all the open sets of $\mathbb R$
$$ f^{-1} \left( \mathcal B \right) = 
\left\{f^{-1} (B) \;|\; B \in \mathcal B \right\} \subseteq \Sigma$$
Two random variables (that is, two measurable functions) $X, Y : \Omega \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$ are called independent if 
$X^{-1}\left( \mathcal B \right),  Y^{-1}\left( \mathcal B \right)$ are independent. Now consider the function $Z = g \circ X$. In order that $Z$ be a random variable, $g$ needs to be a borel function (that is, measurable as function from $(\mathbb R, \mathcal B)$ to $R$). If $g$ is a borel function then 
$$ Z^{-1}\left( \mathcal B \right) =\left( g \circ X\right)^{-1} \left( \mathcal B \right) =
 X^{-1} \left( g^{-1}(\mathcal B) \right) \subseteq 
X^{-1}\left( \mathcal B \right) $$
And this finishes the proof.
Recall, that the borel σ-albebra of $\mathbb R$ is generated by all the sets of the form $\left( -\infty, \theta\right]$ and one can prove that (1)
$$ f^{-1} \left( \mathcal B \right) = 
\sigma \left( \left\{f^{-1} \left( (-\infty, \theta]\right) \;|\; \theta \in \mathbb R \right\}  \right)$$
and that (2) if $\Sigma_1, \Sigma_2$ are independent and closed to finite intersections, then so do their σ-algebras $\sigma(\Sigma_1), \sigma(\Sigma_2)$